# Reference Request - Subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

I'm wondering that is there a result on **determining all subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$**, for $n \geq 1$ and $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite group with $q=p^\ell$ elements, $p$ is a prime.

*Motivation*: My motivation is from the answer by myself in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4491919/749743) (See the first remark at the end of that answer).

Or maybe a broder question: Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, then can we classify all subgroups of $G(\mathbb{F}_q)$? Are there any positive results or any conjectural results? (For example, $G=\mathrm{GL}_n, \mathrm{SL}_n, \mathrm{Sp}_{2n}$ and so on)

---

**Edit**: I'm so sorry if I haven't make myself clear. By an elementary counting, we see that $\# \operatorname{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is of order $q(q+1)(q-1)^2$, so by Lagrange theorem, for any subgroup $H \leq \operatorname{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_q)$, order of $H$ divides $q(q+1)(q-1)^2$. So by *"classifying"* or *"determining"*, I mean for any divisor $d$ of $q(q+1)(q-1)^2$,

1. Does there exist a subgroup $H$ of $\operatorname{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ of order $d$?
2. If there exists such a subgroup $H$ of order $d$, can we list all the isomorphism classes of such subgroups of order $d$? (It's better to explicit write out what matrices occur in $H$.)

And similar question for general $\operatorname{GL}_n$.

My motivation is that I have calculated that a certain Galois group $H$ is a subgroup of $G:= \operatorname{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ of order $q(q+1)(q-1)$. So can we directly settle down the group structure of $H$ by merely knowing the order? If unfortunately we cannot, then a list of isomorphism classes of subgroups of $G$ of order $q(q+1)(q-1)$ may also help since we can exclude some possibilities by examine the relations of certain elements in the Galois group.

Comment: What sort of classification are you looking for? Note that permutation matrices give an embedding of $S_n$ into $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ for any field $k$, so by Cayley's theorem, every finite group of order $n$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$.

Comment: @DanielHast Thank you for your comment! Now I have added more details in the post and hope that it is clearer.

Comment: The conjugacy classes of individual matrices are fairly-simply determined by the possible elementary-divisors, via the structure theorem for finitely-generated abelian groups, etc. But _subgroups_ is waaaaay more complicated, I think. Certainly some _nice_ subgroups can be understood, via ideas from algebraic groups... but, as @DanielHast observes, it's not feasible to classify subgroups of $S_n$, and so on...

Comment: @paulgarrett Thank you! Now via Daniel and your comments, I see how challenging this task is. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximal subgroups of classical groups over finite field were classified in classical papers by Aschbacher in the late 1980s (in the Annals of Math, if memory serves). The papers are very long, very difficult, and are known to have some bugs (since fixed).

Comment: It is worth observing that the final category in Aschbacher's theorem consists of groups that act absolutely irreducibly, cannot be defined over a proper subfield, and are almost simple modulo scalars. So we don't really have a complete classification - for that we would need to know all irreducible projective representations of all finite almost simple groups over all finite fields.

Comment: Thank you Igor Rivin for your help! I shall look them up, and thanks @Derek Holt for your helpful comment! :)