# Find $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$, where $K=F_q(T)$ and $L$ is the splitting field of $p(x)=Tx+x^q+T^q x^{q^2}$.

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

> Let $K=F_q(T)$ and $L$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $p(x)=Tx+x^q+T^q x^{q^2}$ over $K$. Find the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$.

This is from homework of Drinfeld modules. Thanks for the help of my two classmates and the notes http://personal.psu.edu/mup17/Research/ODM.pdf, I know the Galois group of this polynomial $\text{Gal}(K(\phi[T])/K) $ is contained in $\text{GL}_2 (F_q) $ where $\phi[T]$ is the roots of $\phi_T (x)=Tx+x^q +T^q x^{q^2 -1}$ which is a $F_q$-module of rank two.(Refer to the notes http://personal.psu.edu/mup17/Research/ODM.pdf). In fact, this is contained in $\text{SL}_2 (F_q) $.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: In [this recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4490006/11619) the asker told that somebody made the claim that the Galois group you are asking about is isomorphic to $SL_2(\Bbb{F}_q)$. From the theory of linearized polynomials it does follow that we can think of the Galois group as a subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_q)$ because its roots form a 2-dimensional space over $\Bbb{F}_q$. Mind you, you should follow the lead of Hetong Xu in providing context to your question.

Comment: See [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). This topic is rather rare, so I also want to make the reminder that if you are Hetong Xu, and accidentally lost your login credentials, then use the "Contact Us" -button in the bottom. The SE staff can help.

Comment: Thanks, this problem has been solved. This is from my homework of Drinfeld modules.

Comment: In that case you could post an answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be a $F_q$-basis of $\phi[T]$. Then
$$
\phi_T(x)=T^{q} \prod_{m, n \in \mathbb{F}_{q}}(x+m \alpha+n \beta)=T^{q} \frac{\Delta(\alpha, \beta, x)}{\Delta(\alpha, \beta)}
$$
Comparing the coefficient of $x$-term we get $(T \Delta(\alpha, \beta))^{q-1}=1$. Thus $\Delta(\alpha, \beta)=m / T \in K$ for some $m \in F_q^\times.$ Then $\forall \sigma=\left(\begin{array}{ll}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right) \in \text{Gal}(K(\phi[T])/K) \subset \mathrm{GL}_{2}\left(F_q\right)$,
$$
\sigma(\Delta(\alpha, \beta))=\Delta(\sigma(\alpha, \beta))=\Delta(a \alpha+b \beta, c \alpha+d \beta)=\operatorname{det}(\sigma) \Delta(\alpha, \beta) .
$$Since $\Delta(\alpha, \beta) \in K$, then $\text{det}(\sigma)=1$ and hence $\sigma \in \text{SL}_2 (F_q) $. Next, using the following fact from the notes http://personal.psu.edu/mup17/Research/ODM.pdf.

Let $\phi$ be a Drinfeld module of rank $r$ over $K$. Note that we can write $\phi_{T}(x)=x f\left(x^{q-1}\right)$, where $f(x) \in K[x]$ is a polynomial of degree $\left(q^{r}-1\right) /(q-1)$. Show that the splitting field of $f(x)$ is the subfield of $K(\phi[T])$ fixed by $\pi_{T}\left(G_{K}\right) \cap Z\left(F_q\right)$, where $Z\left(F_{q}\right)$ denotes the center of $\mathrm{GL}_{r}\left(F_q\right)$.

In this case, $\pi_T (G_K) \subset \text{SL}_2 (F_q) $ and then the order of $\pi_{T}\left(G_{K}\right) \cap Z\left(F_q\right)$ is less than 2 and $f(y)=T^2 +y+y^{q+1}$. So we know $[K(\phi[T]):K_f ] \le 2$.  Let $S=T^2$, then $f(y)=S+y+y^{q+1}$. Let L be the spliting field of $f$ over $F_q (S)$. This is the case of this question [Computing the Galois group of the splitting field of $X^{q+1} + X + T$ over the function field $\mathbb{F}_q(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490006/computing-the-galois-group-of-the-splitting-field-of-xq1-x-t-over-the). So we know $[L:F_q (S)]= q(q+1)(q-1)$. Then $[K_f :K]\ge \frac{q(q-1)(q+1)}{2}$. So $Gal(K(\phi[T])/K)$ is the normal subgroup of $\text{SL}_2 (F_q)$ of index at most 2. But $\mathrm{SL}_{2}\left(F_q\right)$ has no normal subgroup of index two because its commutator subgroup is itself. Then $\text{Gal}(K(\phi[T])/K)=\mathrm{SL}_{2}\left(F_q\right)$.